# Можно ли изменить свойства у нескольких кнопок при загрузке формы WinForms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-core

Имеется форма с множеством зеленых кнопок
Хочу сделать, чтобы при запуске программы некоторые из них, которые удовлетворяют условию были красными, но какие именно я не знаю и сколько их

Comment: Без кода или хотя бы более подробного объяснения не совсем ясно, что надо сделать

Comment: нужно пройтись по элементам формы,
определить какие из них кнопки,
проверить название кнопки на наличие в списке
и изменить ёё цвет
понимаю вроде решается легко, я не знаю как сделать)

Comment: Знакомы с c# для winforms?

Comment: foreach (var item in this.Controls)
            {
                if (item is Button)
                {
                    if (lst.Contains((item).Name))
                    {
                        item.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    }
                }
            }
это как я сделал и мне вышла ошибка "System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."

Comment: Эта ошибка означает, что Вы пытаетесь узнать что-то про элемент, значение которому еще не присвоено, т.е. = null, может быть это в Вашем случае возникает потому, что Вы пытаетесь узнать и установить свойства кнопки(ее название и цвет) в момент до ее появления), => Вы пытаетесь это сделать до момента инициализации формы. Можете кинуть скрин с кодом, или хотя бы сказать, где Вы пишете код, который написали в комментарии?

Comment: спасибо за ответ, но я уже сам разобрался)